# Styling unordered lists in for each statements

Tags: php, css

I have a ul that contains a set of `lis and divs` created by a for each loop, The `uls` and `lis` are there so that the lis are sortable, i.e drag and drop is enabled, the images are displaying on the next line not close to each other, please what may be the cause

This is my code

```
.img-w {
        position: relative;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 150px;
        width: 200px;
    } 
<ul class="reorder-photos-list">
   @foreach ($images_ext as $image)
   <div style="width: auto;height: auto">
      <li id="{{$image->id}}">
         <div class="img-w " id="{{$image->id}}"style="background-image: url('{{$image->filename}}')"data-src="{{$image->filename}}">
            {{-- <a href=""> <img class="mb-2 uploaded-photos " src="{{$image->filename}}" alt=""></a>!--}}
         </div>
      </li>
      <span style="color: #333333;position: relative;width: 100%;text-align: justify;
         display: inline;">{{$image->description}} <i class="fa fa-upload"
         style="margin-left: 10px; color:#333333;"></i><br/> <br/></span>
   </div>
   @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: You've broken a few rules by placing `div` and `span` outside of `li` in a `ul` block.

Comment: @incrediblehat what do you suggest I do, I want to display images with their descriptions under them with all images side by side, while also making them drag and droppable

Comment: The example by @Chris should get you started. It eliminates the UL and just makes a series of floated boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Div and li are block element, so naturally will display on the next line.. Unless you want to float them or change the display to inline.

try to edit your html and css code as below;

```
<style>
    .img-box{
        float: left;
    }
    .img-w {
        position: relative;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 150px;
        width: 200px;
    }
    .clearfix{
        clear: both;
    }
</style>
@foreach ($images_ext as $image)
    <div class="img-box">
        <div class="img-w" id="{{$image->id}}"style="background-image: url('{{$image->filename}}')"data-src="{{$image->filename}}">
            {{-- <a href=""> <img class="mb-2 uploaded-photos " src="{{$image->filename}}" alt=""></a>!--}}
        </div>
        <span style="color: #333333;position: relative;width: 100%;text-align: justify;
         display: inline;">{{$image->description}} <i class="fa fa-upload" style="margin-left: 10px; color:#333333;"></i></span>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Then use clearfix to clear the float

To include UL and Li, use the code below;

```
<ul>
    @foreach ($images_ext as $image)

        <li class="img-box">
            <div class="img-w" id="{{$image->id}}"style="background-image: url('gig.png')"data-src="{{$image->filename}}">
                {{-- <a href=""> <img class="mb-2 uploaded-photos " src="{{$image->filename}}" alt=""></a>!--}}
            </div>
            <span style="color: #333333;position: relative;width: 100%;text-align: justify;
             display: inline;">{{$image->description}} <i class="fa fa-upload" style="margin-left: 10px; color:#333333;"></i></span>
        </li>

    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: I want to display the images side by side not on new lines

Comment: You want both the description and the image to be on the same line right?

Comment: float the class name  .img-w

Comment: Chris where should I put the ul and Li they're important for my job

Comment: UL and LI is not important for brevity .. but, if you insist, I can change the code to reflect UL and LI. what do you say?

Comment: Yes please change

Comment: I've edited the code to reflect both with the UL, LI and the one without UL and LI